# c#: Chain asynchronous methods

Tags: c#, async-await, task, method-chaining

I've found a piece of code showing how to chain asynchronous methods. Here is the code:

```
    public static class ExtensionMethod
    {
        public static async Task<TResult> MapAsync<TSource, TResult>(
            this Task<TSource> @this,
            Func<TSource, Task<TResult>> fn)
        {
            return await fn(await @this);
        }
    }

    public partial class Program
    {
        public async static Task<int> FunctionA
            (int a) => await Task.FromResult(a * 1);

        public async static Task<int> FunctionB(
            int b) => await Task.FromResult(b * 2);

        public async static Task<int> FunctionC(
            int c) => await Task.FromResult(c * 3);

        public async static void AsyncChain()
        {
            int i = await FunctionC(10)
                .MapAsync(FunctionB)
                .MapAsync(FunctionA);

            Console.WriteLine("The result = {0}", i);
        }
    }
```

But I don't understand why inside the extension method `MapAsync` we have `await fn(await @this)`?

Can someone explain me this, please?

Comment: No need at all to use anything else than the provided `ContinueWith`. Or you didn't understood for what is this code or the one who wrote this don't know too much about async. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Because you have to `await` each Task and when chaining tasks together the only place where you can put these awaits is in `MapAsync` Of course you don't need this logic, because you could just write a couple of `await`'s yourself...

Comment: But the point was not to chain tasks, but also asynchronous and synchronous to create a fluent api. If I would use ContinueWith, then I would need to call .Result.AnotherMethod after this and not this was the purpose

Comment: you are waiting both the original task...AND the next function call

Comment: So you're saying that await @this is waiting the current task to finish and await fn is to wait the task from the parameter to finish?

Comment: This code only works with Tasks, it can't "mix" synchronous calls.

Comment: then how to chain asynchronous and synchronous methods without using .Result from the ask?

Comment: _"I don't understand why inside the extension method MapAsync we have await fn(await @this)?"_ -- what about it don't you understand? Please be specific. It is true that it's not actually needed. The extension method could just as easily have returned the task instead of awaiting it (and then not been an `async` method at all). But there's nothing wrong per se with the code you're looking at. The `await` in that context has the same meaning and effect it would anywhere else. So, what don't you understand?

Comment: @BudaGavril "then how to chain asynchronous and synchronous methods without using .Result". By not using "wrappers" like the one you showed us. Just write one `await YourMethodAsync()` per line and add synchronous code between these awaits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is because in order to get the value of the previous call (in this case the value stored within the Task `@this`) it must be awaited. Because `await` is now being used in the method and it must be marked as `async`, you can now no longer simply return the result from `fn` because it's a Task. (As I'm sure you are aware, and in very simple terms, marking the method as async means that the method signature sort of ignores the Task and just wants an instance of the generic type as the return or nothing if it's not using the genric version of `Task`.)

In response to your comment about chaining both sync vs async methods, this approach of using Task would still work for sync methods, you just have to *pretend* that its async by wrapping the result in a task (which is already marked as completed). Something like this:

```
public async static Task<int> AsyncFunction(int x) 
    => await SomeAsyncMethodThatReturnsTaskOfInt();

public static Task<int> SyncFunction(int x) 
    => Task.FromResult(SomeSyncMethodThatReturnsInt());

public async static void AsyncChain()
{
    int i = await AsyncFunction(10)
        .MapAsync(SyncFunction);

    Console.WriteLine("The result = {0}", i);
}
```

You *can* remove all the async/awaits from the FunctionA, FunctionB and FunctionC definitions as they can just return the task.

There is a nice article on [Eliding await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html) by Stephen Cleary for a better explanation of when you should and shouldn't use await when the only thing the method is doing is returning `Task`.

Having said all that, Gusman's comment is completely correct that this is total overkill for a fairly simple [ContinueWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith(v=vs.110).aspx)